# Microchip C18 - Weird code behavior (maybe extended-mode / non-extended-mode related)

Tags: c, microchip, pic18

I have this weird problem with the Microchip C18 compiler for PIC18F67J60.

I have created a very simple function that should return the index of a Sub-String in a larger String.

I don't know whats wrong, but the behavior seems to be related to wether extended mode is enabled or not.

With Extended-Mode enabled in MPLAB.X I get:

- The `memcmppgm2ram` function returns zero all the time.

With Extended-Mode disabled in MPLAB.X I get:

- The value of iterator variable `i` counts as: `0, 1, 3, 7, 15, 21`

I'm thinking some stack issue or something, because this is really weird. 
The complete code is shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char bigString[] = "this is a big string";

unsigned char findSubStr(char *str, const rom char *subStr, unsigned char n, unsigned char m)
{
    unsigned char i;

    for (i=0; i < n-m; i++)
    {
        if(0 == memcmppgm2ram(&str[i], (const far rom void*)subStr, m))
            return i;
    }
    return n; // not found
}

void main(void)
{
    char n;

    n = findSubStr(bigString, (const rom void*)"big", sizeof(bigString), 3); 
}
```

Comment: Not that I'm sure it could cause your problem, but does memcmppgm2ram really take a far pointer?

Comment: Yes indeed: signed char memcmppgm2ram (auto void *s1, auto const MEM_MODEL rom void *s2, auto sizeram_t n); MEM_MODEL is defines as far

Answer (score 0):

`memcmppgm2ram()` expects a pointer to data memory (ram) as its first argument. You are passing a pointer to a string literal, which is located in program memory (rom).

You can use `memcmppgm()` instead, or copy the other string to ram using `memcpypgm2ram()` or `strcpypgm2ram()`.

Unfortunately I can't test this, as I don't have access to this compiler at the moment.